# FindReferencesAsync doesn't return references across projects

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to find all the references of a type symbol using `FindReferencesAsync`. It works well for references within a C# project; however, cross-project references don't appear. Here is the code that I am using.

```
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(_sourceFile.GetSyntaxTree());
ISymbol classSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeDeclarationSyntax);
referencedSymbols.AddRange(SymbolFinder
                    .FindReferencesAsync(classSymbol, _solution)
                    .Result.ToList());
```

Comment: Just do be clear, do you compilation have a reference to the project that is contain a using type?

Comment: The loaded project shows a project reference in ProjectReferences attribute. However, compilation diagnostics show errors (type or namespace 'Lib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: How are you opening the project and creating the compilation? You may need to manually add `ProjectReferences` yourself. This is probably the case if you're seeing compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable time on this problem. I tried, among others, to add meta-references and project references but nothing worked. Finally, I was able to resolve it by looking at the Diagnostic information provided while creating an instance of a project. Once all the critical issues reported in diagnostics are resolved, I could see all the references of a symbol even across the projects.